Compiling with make results in requires dynamic R_X86_64_PC32 reloc against
I am very new to C and Cmake in general and I am trying to build a software I cloned from github (for my research use) I use cmake .. and eveything build fine but when I try to run make I get
requires dynamic R_X86_64_PC32 reloc against 

I have no idea what to do and no searching was helpful. I would appreciate a very rookie explanation and solution. Bests

That looks like only part of an error message - does it go on to mention -fPIC? Regardless, I suggest you [edit] your question to include a larger part of the make output for context - and mention the specific github repository you cloned
